# Partions on a partitioned table getting created with the same partition number in Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am creating a table with partitioning logic. Below is the partition function and scheme:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate datetime2 = '20230401';
DECLARE @YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction (datetime2) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (';  

DECLARE @i datetime2 = @StartDate;  
WHILE @i < '20300101'  
BEGIN  
    SET @YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10)) + '''' + N', ';  
    SET @i = DATEADD(MM, 3, @i);  
END  
SET @YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(10))+ '''' + N');';  
--PRINT @YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction;
EXEC sp_executesql @YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction; 
GO
```

If you run the bloc to create the partition function uncommenting the PRINT statement, you'll see the below:

```sql
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction (datetime2) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('2023-04-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-10-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-07-01', '2024-10-01', '2025-01-01', '2025-04-01', '2025-07-01', '2025-10-01', '2026-01-01', '2026-04-01', '2026-07-01', '2026-10-01', '2027-01-01', '2027-04-01', '2027-07-01', '2027-10-01', '2028-01-01', '2028-04-01', '2028-07-01', '2028-10-01', '2029-01-01', '2029-04-01', '2029-07-01', '2029-10-01', '2030-01-01');
```

```sql
-- Partition scheme that maps to the PRIMARY filegroup
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME YearlyQuartersPartitionScheme
AS PARTITION YearlyQuartersPartitionFunction
ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
```

And I'm using this scheme to create a table using the below DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AddedUtc] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IsTest] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON YearlyQuartersPartitionScheme(AddedUtc) ON PRIMARY;
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_CompanyId] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [CompanyId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit],(0))) FOR [IsTest]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_Companies_CompanyId] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_Companies_CompanyId]
GO
```

If I check the partitions created for this table, I see that all partitions have the same partition_number value. This is wrong.

Can someone point if I'm doing something blatantly wrong.

I notice that the data_space_id of the partition scheme does not match the data_space_id of the indexes on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes are all `ON PRIMARY` not `ON YearlyQuartersPartitionScheme` so they are not partitioned at all. The reason you are getting multiple rows in `sys.partitions` is because you have multiple indexes, but all of them only have one partition.

Instead you are going to have to recreate your PK as a non-clustered index, and create a new clustered index which is partitioned.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable];

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_Partitioning] ON [dbo].[MyTable] (
  AddedUtc,
  Id
) ON YearlyQuartersPartitionScheme;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY];
```